# Using JQuery Tokeninput or Tagit with Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-tokeninput, tag-it

I am trying to use jquery token input with django. I tried using the 'simple local data search' example from http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/. It is not working in my code. I have downloaded the example and pasted the css and js files in my static folder and those files do get loaded in my template but I am just not able to make it work. Here is the working demo.html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/token-input.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>jQuery Tokeninput Demos</h1>


<h2>Simple Local Data Search</h2>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="demo-input-local" name="blah" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#demo-input-local").tokenInput([
            {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
            {id: 11, name: "Python"},
            {id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
            {id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
            {id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
            {id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
            {id: 29, name: "C#"},
            {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
            {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
            {id: 41, name: "C"},
            {id: 43, name: "C++"},
            {id: 47, name: "Java"}
        ]);
    });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this demo is working fine. I has used the same code in my template but it does not work at all. Here is my template code-

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_markdown %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

{{form.media}}

<h2>Simple Local Data Search</h2>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="demo-input-local" name="blah" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('working');
        $("#demo-input-local").tokenInput([
            {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
            {id: 11, name: "Python"},
            {id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
            {id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
            {id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
            {id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
            {id: 29, name: "C#"},
            {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
            {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
            {id: 41, name: "C"},
            {id: 43, name: "C++"},
            {id: 47, name: "Java"}
        ]);
    });
    </script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the base.html file from which this file extends. It contains all the necessary headers -

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
{{ form.media }}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/djtokeninput.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/jquery-tokeninput-1.6.0-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
    });
});
</script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/token-input.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}">
</head>
```

The javascript function is running and I am also able to get 'Would submit' alert boxes from the base.html when i click on submit. But I am not getting any other tokeninput functionality.

I tried using TagIt was well. Simple code. All js and css files are loading. I have exact same code in in the modified example file from tag it docs and my django templates and here is the result difference -
First my example.html file - 
[image]

and here is my django page using the same code! -

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening!

New base.html-

```
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 {{ form.media }}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- The real deal -->
<script src="/static/js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];



        //-------------------------------
        // Preloading data in markup
        //-------------------------------
        $('#myULTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags, // this param is of course optional. it's for autocomplete.
            // configure the name of the input field (will be submitted with form), default: item[tags]
            itemName: 'item',
            fieldName: 'tags'
        });

        //-------------------------------
        // Tag events
        //-------------------------------
        var eventTags = $('#eventTags');

        var addEvent = function(text) {
            $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
        };

        eventTags.tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            beforeTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
                if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                    addEvent('beforeTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                }
            },
            afterTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
                if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                    addEvent('afterTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                }
            },
            beforeTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
                addEvent('beforeTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
            },
            afterTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
                addEvent('afterTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
            },
            onTagClicked: function(evt, ui) {
                addEvent('onTagClicked: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
            },
            onTagExists: function(evt, ui) {
                addEvent('onTagExists: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.existingTag));
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="/static/css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/static/css/tagit.ui-zendesk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}">

<title>Pythonic Verses</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="{% static 'css/starter-template.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: if you want to use select multiple items from a predefined list, using autocompletion  i can suggest you to try JQuery Tag-it  http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/ because i find it very simple and easy

Comment: @CY5, I just tried using that as well, even it is not working, I simply followed the docs, did not change anything but still nothing is working, I will add details in question.

Comment: Is there a reason you have three different versions of jQuery referenced? That's probably not a good thing.

Comment: @Chris I have edited the code and removed all except the latest version, I had put them to see if it works with anyone in particular

Comment: Is there an error in the developer console?

Comment: @Chris yeah, there are now, couldn't see them earlier, maybe they were'nt there or something, but I got a couple of errors saying JQuery is not defined in different places!

Comment: Can you edit your base.html to the updated version?

Comment: @Chris added new base.html code in the end and the errors are not in my javascript files, they are jquery.init.js and jquery.markup.js files

Comment: @Chris this is the first error- jquery is not defined -   "jQuery = jQuery || django.jQuery;"

Comment: Have you tried something like this question? I have no experience with Django, sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4709298

Comment: @Chris I think those problems have nothing to do with tag it. This is the third error and the one that bothers me, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagit is not a function. This is the function I am using in the new base.html script tag

Comment: @Chris this is the tag-it.js file https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js

Comment: Your issue sounds like jQuery isn't initialised properly. I don't have any experience with Django to advise you on that, although I'd recommend looking at the question I linked.

Comment: @Ekwinder Saini check this DEMO with AutoComplete Feature,try typing c++,java,asp and javascript
http://jsfiddle.net/brfmm7b8/