# JQuery is not defined when using document ready

Tags: jquery, django

I am facing a strange behavior trying to execute the:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

with Jquery.

I have a script in which right now is inside a:

```
  window.addEventListener
```

Inside the script I use repeatedly Jquery. Now I want to replace the window.addEventListener:

```
window.addEventListener("map:init", function (e) {
```

with:

```
$('#add_geometry').on(("map:init", function (e) {
```

And I also want to include all the script inside the:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

When I try to do this I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I know that JQuery is loaded on time. As the application is build with Django, I am not sure if this is an issue related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709298/difficulty-with-django-and-jquery-why-is-undefined-in-the-admin-app)

I tried the recommendations in the above link but didn't really work.
Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: Passing explecitely `$` to handler param would fix it: `$(document).ready(function($) { /* $ is still jQuery */ });`  `$` would loose jQuery reference if e.g jQuery noConflict() method is used (called after document ready snippet). A more robust solution would be to use: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...});`

Comment: Yes. I did. Cause I do use Jquery in lines of code under the  window.addEventListener

Comment: the code of the template would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Please **add Jquery file** in your code.

```
It seems you have not reference Jquery file in your page before your Jquery code execute.
```

You can add like below code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: As I mention above I do use jquery inside my code. I do load the jquery lib. It seems like that outside the  window.addEventListener the jquery is not recognized.